# Truffle console no compile or init options

Tags: truffle, installation, truffle-compile

While using truffle.cmd console I tried to use the compile option, or even init. 
These options are not available, so I cannot compile using console.

truffle(development)> .help

.break    Sometimes you get stuck, this gets you out

.clear    Break, and also clear the local context

.editor   Enter editor mode

.exit     Exit the repl

.help     Print this help message

.load     Load JS from a file into the REPL session

.save     Save all evaluated commands in this REPL session to a file

truffle(development)>

I tried using truffle in PowerShell but still no resolution: could not see compile, or init options, when using .help

Comment: sounds like you should reinstalling truffle, maybe try using truffle in regular cmd

Answer (score 0):

The follwoing worked for compilation: (the --all aoption for truffle.cmd)

truffle.cmd compile --all

Compiling .\contracts\Adoption.sol...

Compiling .\contracts\Migrations.sol...

Writing artifacts to .\build\contracts